# Code to populate HTML form using AJAX not working? What's the deal?

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Okay, so I am working on a website which has a dropdown menu for a user to select a school name.  Once they select the school name, the address, zip, county, and district fields should automatically be populated.

Sadly, I actually had this working just a few hours ago, but then being who I am, I stupidly tried to perfect my code without saving a copy of what I had.  Now the form population no longer works.  However, I honestly feel like I should be working with the code I have.  I'm very confused.

Could someone please look over my code and tell me why it isn't working?  Thank you!

My PHP code:

```
    <?php
$searchtext = $_GET['name'];

$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

if(!$db)  {
    die("Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error());
}

$useDB = mysql_select_db('hsmathcontest');

if (!$db)  {
    die("Use database failed: " . mysql_error());
}   

$schoolID = mysql_query("SELECT ID,address,city,state,zip FROM schools WHERE name = \"$searchtext\"");
if (!$schoolID)  {
    die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
}

$row = mysql_fetch_row($schoolID);
$ID = $row[0];
$addr = $row[1];
$city = $row[2];
$state = $row[3];
$zip = $row[4];

$county = mysql_query("SELECT ID,name FROM county WHERE schoolID = \"$ID\"");
if (!$county)  {
    die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($county))  {
    $countyID = $row[0];
    $countyName = $row[1];
}

$district = mysql_query("SELECT ID,district FROM district WHERE ID = \"$countyID\"");
if (!$district)  {
    die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
}

$row = mysql_fetch_array($district);
$districtID = $row[0];
$districtName = $row[1];

$fullAddress = $addr." ".$city." ".$state;

$data = $fullAddress . "," . $zip . "," . $countyName . "," . $districtName;
echo $data;

    ?>
```

And my Javascript code:

```
    function populateForm()  {
  //get school chosen by user
  var schoolSelected = document.getElementById("schoolName").value;

  var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
  XHR.open('GET', "lookup.php?name="+schoolSelected, true);
  XHR.onreadystatechange = function(){
    try  {
        if(XHR.readyState === 4 && XHR.status === 200)  {
            var data = XHR.responseText.split(",");
            document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = data[0];
            document.getElementById('zip').innerHTML = data[1];
            document.getElementById('county').innerHTML = data[2];
            document.getElementById('district').innerHTML = data[3];
        }
    }
    catch (e)  {
        console.error('The server signalled a problem: ' + e.description);
    }
  }
  XHR.send();
    }
```

Finally, the form itself, where the populateForm() function is called onchange:

```
    <form name="register" method = "POST" action="<?PHP $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    If you have already registered  please click <a href = "JavaScript:void(0);" onClick = "goToLogin();">here</a> to login to your account.<br />
    *All fields required.*<br /><br />
    School Name: * <select id = "schoolName" name = "schoolName" required onchange = "populateForm();">
    <option></option>
```

Comment: So what is failing, database, php or javascript??

Comment: I'm not 100% sure.  I know all 3 were working earlier when my code was working.  I really don't understand why it is not longer working.  I'm thinking it is either something with the PHP or Javascript because I am still able to connect to the database to get my dropdown menu.

Comment: Ok, well if you are using chrome/firefox with firebug you can look for js errors in the console, where you are dumping exceptions

Comment: This one and others `\"$ID\"` will be rendered/interpreted as `WHERE schoolID = "$ID""` which will most probably cause an error. You should be using single quotes `WHERE schoolID = '$ID'"` and follow the same for the others. @user2925352

Comment: I found no JS errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the code you uploaded, turns out those "address", "zip" etc. fields you are trying to populate in register.js are input fields, so you need to use .value instead of .innerHTML:

document.getElementById('address').value = data[0];

etc... Just checked it out, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this query is ok:

SELECT ID,district FROM district WHERE ID = \"$countyID\""

looks like you're looking for and ID by providing the same ID... are you sure it shouldn't be "countyID" ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no, I don't think that is it.  I had it working earlier with this select statement.  I'm working with multiple tables so when the user picks the school, for example, it's going to query the other tables for the matching zip, county, etc.

Comment: so you're assuming the county ID is the same as the district ID?

Comment: [See my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250645/code-to-populate-html-form-using-ajax-not-working-whats-the-deal#comment30205166_20250645) @user2925352

Comment: It's only part of the problem. @user2925352

Comment: I took the time of recreating the code on my computer. files are here: http://www.fileflyer.com/view/CLFfEAI. Worked perfectly fine...

Comment: Maybe I'm silly but I just realized your SELECT tag is not closed, as well as the FORM tag. Did you leave it out on purpose? look at my files, I closed those and it worked just fine...

Comment: Thanks, trueicecold.  I'm sorry I had to step away from my computer.  I'm about to check what you did.  I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Okay, trueicecold.  So I couldn't open your files because I can't see to open the .rar file.  I know I need WinRar, but I have a slow Internet connection so that won't be happening today.  However, as for the tags, I have colsed my SELECT and FORM tags with the second and final closing >, right?

Comment: Good catch!  I can't believe I didn't even notice that.  Actually, I did close the select tag further down.  I just forgot to paste that into my post above.  But I did forget to close the form tag so thank you!  But the problem remains.  I'm starting to think something else weird is going on.

Comment: I've reuploaded the files as a zip archive, shouldn't have any problems viewing it now: http://www.fileflyer.com/view/o4gWDCv

Comment: Please look at my new answer I posted.

Comment: Oh, my goodness!  Thank you.  Man, I feel like such a moron right now!  And that really hurts because I had it working earlier.  I must have went back and changed the .value to .innerHTML afterwards.  Thanks for spending practically all day dealing with my stupidity.  :)

Comment: no probs :) btw I couldn't help noticing that while you accepted my answer, you have more questions that have been answered but not accepted by you :) Please show some courtesy and accept those as well if they were helpful enough :)

Comment: Just when in and did that.  I'm new to the site, and I honestly didn't even notice the accept answer option until you today.  :)